# A few question about images uploading

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to upload images to my website, make some image processing(resize, get image size\resolution, convert to jpg format etc ) and then embed it to page of my website.
I have a few question:

- How to check that uploading file is image?
- Where is better store images - mssql or just folder?
- How to detect image type. Is MIME trust source?
- How to make image processing. Is System.Drawing good instrument?

Answer (score 0):

> How to check that uploading file is image?

You could look at the uploaded filename and use the extension but that's not 100% guarantee. Anyone could rename an `.exe` to `.jpg`, so no reliable way. Remember that all you get on the server is a filename and a byte array which could be anything. Another technique consists into looking at the first few bytes of the uploaded file and try to *guess* its type but once again not guaranteed.

> Where is better store images - mssql or just folder?

There is no definite answer. Some prefer files system, others SQL. I prefer storing files on the file system and saving only the path in SQL. Also SQL Server 2008 has a [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949109(SQL.100).aspx) datatype which might be worth checking.

> How to detect image type. Is MIME trust source?

Once again the file extension could be used but not 100% trustworthy.

> How to make image processing. Is System.Drawing good instrument?

Yes GDI+ is good enough to perform basic image processing like resizing for common image types.

Answer (score 0):

1) the cheap way to detect is by extension.  The *mostly* secure way is to read the first few bytes of the header and see if it matches to known image format headers.

2) MSSQL 2008 has a FileStream type which is the best of both worlds.  If you are on an older version of sql server then it's a toss up.  If the images have to be accessible by multiple web servers and portability / backups are a concern then you have to put it in the database server...

If multiple web servers, but portability/backups are not a concern, then store it on a NAS.

If single web server and you *know* it won't be scaled up, then on the local web server file system is ok.

3) Trust no one.  See Item 1.

4) Buy a library or find an open source one.  It will make your life much easier.  Incidentally, this helps with item 1 and 3.  When the image is uploaded, open it with the library.  If the library complains then you can be pretty sure it's not a real image.

You might check into plupload to see what they are doing:  http://www.plupload.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can check out my blog post:

Async-Image upload using JavaScript + ASHX Handler.
http://weblogs.asp.net/rternier/archive/2010/08/18/jquery-image-upload-amp-refresh-using-an-ashx-file.aspx

ServerSide code for Image Uploading (ASHX and image manipulation)
http://weblogs.asp.net/rternier/archive/2010/09/17/jquery-image-upload-amp-refresh-using-an-ashx-file-part-2.aspx

IT will cover a lot of this, but here you go.

how to check if it's an image:
When you are uploading you can check the file extension to see what it is. Once uploaded, you can check the mime type of the file.

I like storing images as binary inside a database. It's a lot easier to manage and I don't need to read/write from the web server hard disk to get the image.

TO do any modifications on the image use System.Drawing.